# Error when __new__ is called from a metaclass

Tags: python

The following code produces an error:

```
class FooMeta(type):
  def __new__(mcl, classname, bases, classdict):
   return type.__new__(mcl, classname, bases, dict())

  def __init__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
    super(FooMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, classdict)

    d = dict()
    for key, item in classdict.items():
      if key.startswith("_"):
        setattr(cls, key, item)
      else:
        d[key] = item
    setattr(cls, '_items', d)

class Foo(object):
  __metaclass__ = FooMeta

class Passing(Foo):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    pass

class Failing(Foo):
  def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
    return super(Failing, cls).__new__(cls)

  def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    pass

fail = Failing()
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../FooMeta,py", line 30, in <module>
    fail = Failing()
TypeError: unbound method __new__() must be called with Failing instance as first argument (got FooMeta instance instead)
```

There appears to be some difference in the way `__new__` is called when called from a metaclass.

1) Anyone know why this is happening?
2) Is there some way to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

If you allow the attributes to be set as is normally done:

```
class FooMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcl, classname, bases, classdict):
        return type.__new__(mcl, classname, bases, classdict)
```

and do not fiddle with them in `__init__`, you see that `Failing.__new__` is normally a staticmethod:

```
class FooMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcl, classname, bases, classdict):
        return type.__new__(mcl, classname, bases, classdict)
        # return type.__new__(mcl, classname, bases, dict())

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
        super(FooMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, classdict)
        d = dict()
        for key, item in classdict.items():
            if key.startswith("_"):
                # setattr(cls, key, item)
                pass
            else:
                d[key] = item
        setattr(cls, '_items', d)

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = FooMeta

class Failing(Foo):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        return super(Failing, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        pass

print(Failing.__dict__['__new__'])
foo = Failing()
```

yields:

```
<staticmethod object at 0xb774ba94>
```

But if you run the code you posted with this print statement tacked on the end:

```
print(Failing.__dict__['__new__'])
foo = Failing()
```

you see that `__new__` has been changed to a function:

```
<function __new__ at 0xb747372c>
```

You can fix this by allowing all the attributes in classdict to be set as would normally be done, and then deleting those attributes which do not start with `_`:

```
class FooMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcl, classname, bases, classdict):
        return type.__new__(mcl, classname, bases, classdict)

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
        super(FooMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, classdict)
        d = dict()
        for key, item in classdict.items():
            if not key.startswith("_"):
                delattr(cls, key)
                d[key] = item
        setattr(cls, '_items', d)

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = FooMeta

class Passing(Foo):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        pass

class Failing(Foo):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        return super(Failing, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        pass

print(Failing.__dict__['__new__'])
foo = Failing()
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, would

    `if key == ("__new__"):
        setattr(cls, key, staticmethod(item))`

also work? Or would that not account for other staticmethods on the class?

Comment: @forivall: Yes, that also works as far as I can see, but the code is uglier and invites the possibility that I am making some error. I think it is safer to just delete the non-private items.